# Find what file opens after redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I use window.open to redirect to another window.

```
window.open("/GamePage.html", "_self", false);
```

How can i find out what file it opens?

I see that it opens some other file (not the one in the folder) because I can't see the changes i make and the only thing that helped is changing the name of the file. Inside this folder there is only one file with this name.

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this?

Comment: You're sure it's not just a caching issue.

Comment: Not sure if its caching issue, never had this problem before. Ia there a way to check?

Comment: You're telling it to open `GamePage.html`. What else do you need to know?

Comment: The problem that it opens some old version of GamePage.html.
I can't see the changes I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slash before the file name.

Comment: didn't help, i still see the page like it was before the updates.

Comment: Make sure the file is on the same directory. Also try clearing your cache.

Comment: its in the same directory and clearing the cache didn't help.
the only thing that helps is changing the name of the file